# Location of storing the code that calculates the discount

Tags: plsql

This question was asked theoretically to me:
You want to create a PL/SQL block of code that calculates discounts on customer orders. This code will be invoked from several places but only within program unit ORDERTOTAL. What is the most appropriate location to store the code that calculates the discount.

I answered "a block of code in the body of the program unit ORDERTOTAL". This is incorrect.
Correct one is "a local sub-program defined within the program unit ORDERTOTAL". Why is it so ?
I thought this ORDERTOTAL is itself a sub-program (procedure/function), which is not so.

Comment: A procedure or function could have its own local procedures and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a local sub-program defined within the program unit ORDERTOTAL" is correct as what the question stated was "This code will be invoked from several places". In other words we have a unit like

```
create function foo
  return number
is
  v_one number := 200;
  v_two number := 10;
begin

  v_one := some complex math operation;

  -- some other code

  v_two := the same complex math operation;

  -- etc..
end;
/
```

so to save repeating that math operation (which is the solution you gave..a block of code in the function itself, repeated as needed) we can do this:

```
create function foo
  return number
is
  v_one number := 200;
  v_two number := 10;

  function calc_math(p_var number)
    return number
  is
  begin
    return complex math operation;
  end calc_math;
begin

  v_one := calc_math(v_one);

  -- some other code

  v_two := calc_math(v_two);

  -- etc..
end;
/
```

thus avoiding code repetition.